# C# Attributes Aren't Supposed to Inherit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Since attributes don't inherit in C# (at least I didn't think they did) - how does the following code still display the Hello popup when the `MyTestMethod` test is run:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseTestClass {
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Foo() {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass : BaseTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod() {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't unless MyTestMethod calls Foo, but that has nothing to do with C# attributes, which incidently CAN be inherited.

Comment: Foo is decorated with the [TestInitialize] attribute, which is being inherited by the TestClass test.  But yeah, as noted, attributes can be inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attributes are inherited by default but this can be disabled - see [AttributeUsage.Inherited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx)

If you decorate the attribute definition with an `AttributeUsage` attribute, you can set this property:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If not working as is make method Foo virtual and just override it, and put the TestInitialize at your TestClass override method

```
 [TestClass]
  public class BaseTestClass
  {

    public virtual void Foo()
    {
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
  }

  [TestClass]
  public class TestClass : BaseTestClass
  {
     [TestInitialize]
    public override void Foo()
    {
      base.Foo();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
      Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - it is working, I just wasn't expecting it to.  I (ignorantly) didn't think attributes could inherit.